# Magento2 disable a new module by default

Tags: magento2, module

I am new to Magento 2. I created a new module using:
[Create Basic module Magento 2 - Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/)

Once it was implemented then by default the module was enabled.
My question is how by default we can disable the module at first. Without the following steps:
 1. Without editing app/etc/config.php.
 2. Without command line

```
bin/magento module:disable Test_Helloworld
```

In Magento 1 we had option to disable a module by default by setting active as  false in app\etc\modules\Test_Helloworld.xml.
Is this option not exist in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in Magento 1 - When you are creating new module , you actually not running any command to installed/enabled it. Its automatically started working.

While in Magento 2 - Whenever you are preparing any new module - you need to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command to installed it.

> **So basically there is not module level settings is available to disabled that module. Magento has replaced that functionality to
>   app/etc/config.php from where you can disabled module manually by
>   changing its status 0 to 1. Or you can disabled it by running command
>   which you mention above.**

**Even though if you look at Magento Core Modules they have also  follows the same structure.**

**Note :** Magento 2 etc/module.xml have only 2 major things are there one is module name and second one is sequence tag which is sometimes necessary.

Comment: @Raghu - Happy to help !! Keep Helping :)

Comment: Thanks @ManthanDave for the information.

Answer (score 1):

In M2, You can do it by the above two methods only. There is no other method to disable module.

Comment: Thanks @BornCoder.